# NVIDIA drivers for video and GPU

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

My workstation has 2 NVIDIA cards installed:

```
NVIDIA QUADRO K2200  driver version: 341.44
NVIDIA TESLA K20     driver version: 347.88
```

My simple question is that should I install the driver separately for each card or just install one driver for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nVidia drivers are unified.  If you download the driver package for both cards, it is likely that they will be the exact same file.  If that's the case, the one driver should work with both cards.

If the files are different, then install the driver with the oldest version number first.  That way, the newer version of the driver for the other card will update things like the nVidia control panel, but will leave the actual driver file for the other card alone.

Comment: I agree, it should be the same driver package that will work for both as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that when I installed 2nd driver, it updated the first one. the installed driver version is the same as the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the driver for the first card and then reboot the computer. It may additionally see the secondary card at that time. In which case, you can stop and just check device manager for both cards. If you don't see the second card after a reboot and driver install, you will need to go find the appropriate driver for the Tesla and install it as well. I believe the Nvidia driver bundle will intelligently search and install drivers for any compatible card it discovers within the same class or series of cards.